# CSS hover block li element disappear border round

Tags: html, css

My problem is that I have block with round corners and list (ul->li) inside it and when I hover on `li` element my block round corners disappear. Can you tell me how to fix it.

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/kolxoznik1/zALFL/4/

HTML

```
            <div id="drop">
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li><a href="#home">Test-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">Test-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#skills">Test-3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
ul{
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#drop {
    background: #F8F8F8;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 180px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -ms-border-radius: 3px;
    -o-border-radius: 3px; 
}
#drop li a {
    color: #333;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#drop li a:hover {
    background: #333;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fix is give `overflow:hidden` to the `div` drop

The issue was when hover on the list item the corners of the list item overlaps the corner of the `ul`.So when you give `overflow:hidden` for the `ul` the overlap is hidden.
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/zALFL/8/)

Answer (score 9):

Its happening because, background of `li` is outside the div, hence curved border does not appear.

Write:

```
#drop {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/zALFL/5/)

Answer (score 2):

Use `last-child` and `first-child` options: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zALFL/6/)**

```
#drop li:first-child a:hover {
     border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px 3px 0 0;
    -ms-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    -o-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}
#drop li:last-child a:hover {
     border-radius:0 0 3px 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:0 0 3px 3px;
    -ms-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    -o-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use border-radius for a elements

```
#drop li:first-child a {
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
}
#drop li:last-child a {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
#drop li a:hover {
background: #333;
color: #FFF;
border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-ms-border-radius: 3px;
-o-border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Comment: NOOO! You got to it before me!

Comment: @Cammy_the_block : type fast next time! :D

Comment: But mine has more exclamation marks so it must be better. I like how you misspelled that.

Comment: But it is wrong! ;) It will round every element, but thats not right.

Comment: Yeah this rounds every element. The overflow:hidden answer is the best one. Although I kind of like the look my solution gives :P And this shows that playing around with css properties can give some unintended but interesting results

Comment: @Yannici It is artistic, gosh! :P You could probably debate that this is what he wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the roundness to the hover! Change the old `#drop li a:hover` to

```
#drop li a:hover {
    background: #333;
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -ms-border-radius: 3px;
    -o-border-radius: 3px; 
}
```

No, before someone asks, I have no clue what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

add this into your css

```
ul li a:hover {
     border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -ms-border-radius: 3px;
    -o-border-radius: 3px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/r3wt/zALFL/24/

```
#drop ul li a {
    color: #333;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#drop ul li a:hover {
    background: #333;
    color: #FFF;
}
#drop ul li:last-child a {
    border-radius: 3px !important;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px !important;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px !important;
}
#drop ul li:first-child a {
    border-radius: 3px !important;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px !important;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed your problem in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zALFL/27/)

`#drop li a {
        border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -ms-border-radius: 3px;
    -o-border-radius: 3px;
    color: #333;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
}`